# Kubernetes client python API 401 accessing pod autoscalers

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I've got a python process that will update values on the horizontal pod autoscalers.

However, when I'm running the command I'm seeing 401 errors;

```
Exception when calling AutoscalingV1Api->patch_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'foo', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 31 Aug 2023 00:01:53 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}


Exception when calling AutoscalingV1Api->read_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'bar', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Thu, 31 Aug 2023 00:01:53 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

The pod that is running this process is using a service account named `scale-workloads-identity`.

In helm I've defined role bindings that should give permissions for the autoscaler to the service account;

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: scale-workloads-identity@{{ .Values.gcloud.project }}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: scale-workloads-identity
  labels:
    name: scale-workloads-identity
    helm.sh/chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    build: {{ .Values.global.build | quote }}
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: scale-workloads-identity-role
  labels:
    name: scale-workloads-identity-role
    helm.sh/chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    build: {{ .Values.global.build | quote }}
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "autoscaling"
  resources:
  - "horizontalpodautoscalers"
  verbs:
  - "get"
  - "patch"
  - "update"
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: scale-workloads-identity-role-binding
  labels:
    name: scale-workloads-identity-role-binding
    helm.sh/chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    build: {{ .Values.global.build | quote }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: scale-workloads-identity-role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: scale-workloads-identity
```

The above exceptions are thrown by the command as it's trying to access the API;

```
        api = kubernetes.client.AutoscalingV1Api(
            kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration)
        )

        try:
            api.patch_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler(
                "nginx",
                namespace,
                [
                    {
                        "op": "replace",
                        "path": "/spec/minReplicas",
                        "value": min_nginx_replicas,
                    }
                ],
            )
        except ApiException as e:
            print(
                "Exception when calling AutoscalingV1Api->"
                f"patch_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler: {e}"
            )

        try:
            read = api.read_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler(
                "my-app", namespace
            )
        except ApiException as e:
            print(
                "Exception when calling AutoscalingV1Api->"
                f"read_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler: {e}"
            )
```